# I want to use the Token in URLSession with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have the token in authorization Type Bearer Token in URLSession

I always use alamofire and swiftjson

Unfortunately I searched a lot and couldn't find the right way in URLSession

```
I have this token : 28|cSTxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Example
```

But it gives nil

```
struct model : Codable, Identifiable {

let id = UUID()
var name : String
}
class modelapiClass : ObservableObject {


@Published var modelBib : [model] = []

func getData() {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxxx") else {
        return
    }
    let token = "28|cSTxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" Example
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.setValue( token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let uelSession = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in

        do {
            let dataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([model].self, from: data!)
            print(dataModel)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.modelBib = dataModel
            }
        } catch _ {
            
        }
    }
    uelSession.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: At least you have to **use** the request : `dataTask(with: request) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this (in addition to vadian comment):

```
 request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Comment: Problem is  He is not using `request`   variable

Comment: yes, I know, that is why I added: `(in addition to vadian comment)`